# svg icon loading by using webview in Android jellybean and kitkat unspported

Tags: android

I am working on application which loads svg icon by using webview. The url contains icons which are coming from .svg file. Problem is icons are rendering properly in higher versions of Android, but in android kitkat and jelly bean versions that icon it shows rendering problem. not working. Any one know what is the problem? or Is any method to load svg icon load in android.

Comment: Add into build.gradle  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0' this library and use it like this 
Glide.with(this).load(svg_imge).into(imageView);

Comment: Glide not supporting svg from url. so i tried webview .